# jquery validator for multiple dynamically created checkbox or radio groups

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, jquery-validate

I have a form that has multiple sets of checkbox and/or radio groups that are dynamically created from sql data. I need to validate that at least 1 checkbox (or a radio button) is checked in each group. 
HTML output similar to this:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name"30001" id"30001-1" class="req_question" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name"30001" id"30001-2" class="req_question" value="2">
</td>
<td>    
    <input type="checkbox" name"30002" id"30002-1" class="req_question" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name"30002" id"30002-2" class="req_question" value="2">
</td>
<td>        
    <input type="radio" name"30003" id"30003-1" class="req_question" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name"30003" id"30003-2" class="req_question" value="2">
</td>
<td>    
    <input type="radio" name"30004" id"30004-1" class="req_question" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name"30004" id"30004-2" class="req_question" value="2">
</td>
```

I have the following addMethod, but this just checks for 1 button and then all groups are validated:

```
$.validator.addMethod('req_question', function(value) {
  return $('.req_question:checked').size() > 0;
}, 'Please check at least one box.');
```

I believe that this is grabbing the 'req_question' class and validating all the groups at once. 
How can I "find" all of the disparate groups and validate them individually, when I have no way to know how many there are, or what they are named?

Answer (score 3):

**Quote OP**:

> *"How can I 'find' all of the disparate groups and validate them
>   individually, when I have no way to know how many there are, or what
>   they are named?"*

What do you mean by "find"?  Your code is already finding them.

What you're already doing now is exactly how you'd validate something when you don't know all the `name`'s or how many you have.  The `req_question`  validation method/rule is automatically applied to every input that contains `class="req_question"` even if you don't know how many or their individual `name`'s.

---

---

**Your HTML Markup:**

```
name"30004" id"30004-2"
```

There are two problems here:

1)  You're missing the equals sign, `=`, on both.  Should be `name="30004" id="30004-2"`

2)  Typically, `name` and `id` values are not allowed to start with numbers.  Although HTML5 will allow it, IMO, it's still bad coding practice.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/594235

---

---

**Your Custom Method:**

```
$.validator.addMethod('req_question', function(value) {
    return $('.req_question:checked').size() > 0;
}, 'Please check at least one box.');
```

Your function is broken because `$('.req_question:checked')` targets all of these checked elements at once.  The function in `addMethod` takes two arguments, `value` and `element`.  The `value` is the current value of the element being validated.  The `element` is the current element being validated.  These keywords are what you use since you only need to target the element being validated.

```
$.validator.addMethod('req_question', function (value, element) {
    return value > 0;
}, 'Please check at least one box.');
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/9y2MB/**

---

**HOWEVER**, you do not need a custom method to do this.  By default, if you apply the `required` rule to these same elements, you will get the same exact result.  I use the `.rules('add')` method to add the `required` rule to all fields of with a `req_question` class.

```
$('.req_question').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: 'Please check at least one box.'
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/9y2MB/1/**

---

**But wait!**  It's even way simpler than that.  Just use `class="required"` instead of `class="req_question"` on all of these elements...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="n30001" id="n30001-1" class="required" value="1" />
```

**DEMO 3:  http://jsfiddle.net/9y2MB/2/**

Comment: Can you please help if I want to require all checkbox validation? @Sparky